# Need Windows CE in 3072L

Tags: windows-ce, platform-builder

I'm trying to create windows CE OS that will run in my industrial CPU using Microsoft Studio 2005. All my tried was failed.

Im trying to build a Windows CE that have

Catalog items view

- Storage

  - Primary disk/storage/master/slave
  - Secondary
- CAB
- CF card
- Device Manager
- Registry flush
- Pci 1710
- Internet explorer
- .netframework
- C++
- Usb
- Uno3072l
- Display
- Audio
- And other basic utilities

I hope that someone will build the windows for me without any error. And share the link here so i can download.

Or, someone who can teach me how to solve the error. I am really stuck.

Answer (score 0):

The Advantech 3072L is a simple x86-basd machine.  You can likely use the x86 BSP that ships with Platform Builder, though Advantech may also have a platform specific BSP for any peripherals.  Without more info on the version of Platform Builder you're using, what you've tried and the errors you're seeing we can't provide much more help than that.